# Match if something is before or after certain word

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to build a pattern to match all counties from a sentence
eg. 
"ABCD XYZ County Herefordshire or Co.Kent or London County"

```
((co(unty)?\s)|(co\.\s?))?(?P<county>[a-z]{4,})(\scounty)?
```

But above pattern will also return "ABCD" as both expressions around "county" are optional.

Do I have to use two separate regular expressions or is there any way around it?

**EDIT**
What I am trying to do is get all the counties from a sentence. I consider word a county name if it is followed by "county" or preceded either of "co.", "co ", "county ". Multiple expressions like that divided by " or " are allowed. Once matched next step would be to remove whole expression eg "Co.London" from original string.

**EDIT 2**
OK sorry for confusion I know my questions isn't clear. What I am trying to do is:
1. User enters something like 'ABCD County XYZ or Co.London or Kent County or county Herefordshire'
2. I want to get anything that is any of: "co.word" or "co word" or "county word" or "word county"  So ideally I should get this: 'ABCD County,County XYZ,Co.London,Kent County,county Herefordshire'
3. I remove 'county' or 'co' etc from matched expression and check each against list of counties I have. If word is a county name I want to remove the whole expression from the original query.

Comment: regexes are applicable only for "regular" languages. What you have there is not regular, unless you explain a bit more about the text you're expecting.

Comment: SO, what exactly should and what shouldn't the regexp match match? Matching one word thatr is followed by "county", but not the "county" itself?

Comment: The only way to discern which direction the regex should go is if you whitelist actual county values and compare the result(s).

Comment: @hjpotter92 I've edited original question

Comment: I actually expected that you want this. See @Cryode's comment then - there is no way for the code to know wether the wort infront or after the "county" is the name. How should it determine that? It can only match those words (both of them), but there is no indication which of those is a county name, unless you have a list of them.

Comment: counties begin with Capital letter - maybe you should recognize this as a county?

Comment: @JohannesH. sorry my example was wrong, corrected that now. I'm fine with matching XYZ in my case. I have a list and I will check all the matches against that list. I just didn't want to do regex inside loop on counties list. I wanted to get all the "possible counties" from query first and then check against my proper list of counties.

Comment: @GrumpyHat I've updated my answer with some extra code, you might want to have a look to see if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: @Joeytje50 thanks but I can't rely on capital letters the query is typed by an user... Maybe I over complicated my question, what Im trying to do is to get and remove anything like 'Co.London' or 'London County' from a query, multiple of these would be allowed divided by word 'or'

Comment: @GrumpyHat and how would you differentiate county names, such as "London" or "Herefordshire", from other words? Do you have a long list of county names to filter? Or do you have another way of differentiating them? I can't give you code unless I know how you are planning to do that. There's no magic "interpreter" that automatically knows the difference between "London" and "Johnny". For computers, they're both simply 6-letter strings starting with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @Joeytje50 I have edited my original question to better explain what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you're looking for by first matching the group that has it before the text you're matching, and then matching it when it's after it. That explanation is probably unclear, so let me illustrate it this way:

You want to match `foo` that's either before or after `bar`:

```
(bar)foo|foo(bar)
```

of course in this case the parentheses are not required, but it's to illustrate that it's a group.

In your case, if I'm understanding it correctly, you'd need the following:

```
((co(unty)?\s)|(co\.\s?))(?P<county>[a-z]{4,})|(?P<county>[a-z]{4,})(\scounty)
```

or with reduced amount of parentheses:

```
(co(unty)?\s|co\.\s?)(?P<county>[a-z]{4,})|(?P<county>[a-z]{4,})\scounty
```

I'm not quite sure what the `(?P` is supposed to mean though. [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/nD6rT2) doesn't recognise it either.

---

In reply to [Johannes' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21651587/1256925#comment32723444_21651643), what you could do is only match words starting with an uppercase letter:

```
([Cc]o(unty|\.)? ?)([A-Z]\w+)|([A-Z]\w+) [Cc]ounty
```

That would also match it if the word is uppercase because it's the start of a sentence, though, so you could prevent it from matching that via:

```
([Cc]o(unty|\.)? ?)([A-Z]\w+)|((?<![.!?] |.\n)[A-Z]\w+) [Cc]ounty
```

then again, if the county name is the start of the sentence, it won't match it again, but that's something you're going to have to choose between. Regex can't make a distinction between a county name and a regular word at the start of a sentence.

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/oX0bL9) of the last mentioned regex.

---

Update per your comments: You can match *every* word that is followed or preceded by one of the named keywords (including ones that are not necessarily county names) by using the following:

```
((?<=county\s)|(?<=co\s)|(?<=co\.))(?P<county>[a-z]{4,})|(?P<county2>[a-z]{4,})(?=\scounty)
```

[**demo**](http://regex101.com/r/qB8xP5).

That uses lookbehinds, so only matches the actual word, not the word "county", so you could even omit the named capturing group, and directly use the list of matches, instead of filtering it to just the named capturing groups. As you can see in the demo, the only actual text matched is the text you're looking for.

Comment: If you got `ABCD County Herefordshire` this would still match `ABCD`. If you swap both alternatives, it will match `Herefordshire`, but unfortunately `London county ABCD` will then match the `ABCD`...

Comment: @JohannesH. I've added some regex that would prevent it from matching `abcd County Therefordshire`, by restricting it to words that start with an uppercase letter only. Regex is not clever enough to know what a county name is or not otherwise though, so this is really the best I can get it. If it needs to be any better, you're going to have to unleash a county-name whitelist.

Comment: Last sentence is exactly my point :) The ?P<> assignes names to capturing groups BTW and is PHP specific.

Comment: According to @GrumpyHat's comment below the question, your answer may be suitable. +1.

Comment: @Joeytje50 although this was not exactly what I needed I think it pointed me (back!) to the right direction, thanks! And this is what I came up with in the end: `/\b(?:(?:(?:co(?:unty)?\s)|(?:co\.\s?))(?:[a-z]{4,}))|(?:(?:[a-z]{4,})(?:\scounty))\b/i`

Comment: @Joeytje50 well actually not, it wont work for `ddd easd fasdf county london` - only 'fasdf county' was returned by preg_match_all :/ im back where I was before I asked this qustion. Clearly, I am missing something.

Comment: @GrumpyHat well that's because it's basically impossible for an automated script to recognise what is a county name and what is not. You said that it should match if 'followed by "county" or preceded either of "co.", "co ", "county "'. Of course the script is going to match 'fasdf' to be a county name: it's followed by "county", so it does meet the requirements you stated in your question. There's no way for the script to know 'fasdf' is not a county name.

Comment: @Joeytje50 I fully understand that! I just want it to return both options: 'fasdf county' and 'county london'

Comment: @GrumpyHat OHHHHHHH That never became clear for me. Let me update my answer, that should be quite easy to do.

Comment: @GrumpyHat is [this](http://regex101.com/r/qB8xP5) what you were looking for? The capturing groups need to be different names, but it does only match the text before or after one of the listed keywords.

Comment: @Joeytje50 I was trying to avoid two named groups :) OK will have look tomorrow, too late here now:) thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Joeytje50 thanks, you have helped me a lot. Here's my final pattern: `((?<=\bcounty\s)|(?<=\bco\s)|(?<=\bco\.)|(?<=\bco\.\s))(?P<a>[a-z]{4,})(?=\b)|(?=\b)(?P<b>[a-z]{4,})(?=\scounty\b)` seems to work well. +1 for introducing lookarounds to me. Please update your answer with the pattern from the link above and I'll match it as the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: @GrumpyHat okay, I've added the link and some further explanation to my answer. I hope the rest of your script goes well, good luck!